# How to open main activity when application was killed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

A = Main Activity
B = Some Activity

1. Normal case
   A > B > Home Button > B
2. Application was killed case
   A > B > Home Button > idle for some time > application killed > open app again > A

How can I do like case 2 ?

**P.S.** I tried to add `android:launchMode="singleTask"` in Manifest. It always start at A but I would like to start at A in case 2 (application was killed) only.

Comment: when you click hone button is second case app is not killed your activity is paused (in background) and it resumes when you return to your app.Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However, if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost. So your activity B is resuming in your case i guess

Comment: do u want to kill the app after some time of pressing the home button ?

Comment: I think the default behavior of Android is exactly what you want.

Comment: @Raghunandan yes, this is normal case but when i press Home button and kill process by Task Manager, afther that i run App agian it go to onCreate() Activity B but i want App go to Activity A.What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this lines in your Application class.  This code will automatically redirect your app to your desired page. if it get killed.

```
public class MYAppApplication extends Application {

    Context context;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();


        context=this;

        MySafetyMethod();
    }


    private void MySafetyMethod() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {                

                System.out.println("inside the process of handling exceptions");
                System.err.println("inside the process of handling exceptions");
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(2);

                startActivity(new Intent(context, YourActivity.class)); 

            }
        });
    }


}
```

hope this helps you. and also dont forget to mention the application name in your manifest .